# Add features to linear layer of transformer

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, transformer

I'm currently using a transformer for a binary text classification task. Besides the raw text I would also like to add some other handpicked features like text length, text date, text author etc.
I was thinking that I could just add these features to the vector just before the linear layer at the end of the transformer. So I would just append the handpicked features to the text embedding.

This seems quite logical to me but I can't really find any sources referencing this topic. Is the described method indeed the way to add additional features to a transformer? Or is there some other way?

Thanks in advance!